# createCriteria returns wrong list size vs HQL list

Tags: hibernate

in my user table i have two users
when trying to select all users with HQL query as follows:

```
getCurrentSession().createQuery("From User").list();
```

it returns the **two elements**, and that's **right**.

but when using createCriteria as follows:

```
getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class).list();
```

it returns **36 element** (the **two elements repeated**)!!!!

any ideas why i am getting such behavior with createCriteria, is that related to hibernate relations ? because in **User** domain i have **ManyToMany** relation with Role domain, is it related to session factory or hibrenate version or hibernate configuration ?

relation:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);
```

i am confused, please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Many-to-many relation with eager fetching. Criteria query will be translated into a SELECT with joins in it, and so in the result you'll have many rows for each User.

To remove duplicates add all the results to a HashSet, or use DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.